# Unable to query from SQLite database: No such table error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to copy a SQLite database.
The code to copy the database is:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.nirmalam.vaishnavismeclass.mydatabaseapplication/databases/";
    private static final String DB_NAME="vaishnavismeclass.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

    public SQLiteDatabase dbSQLite;

    private final Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion>oldVersion)
            copyDBFromResource();
    }

    public void createDatabase(){
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB() {
        boolean dbExist = DBExist();

        if (!dbExist){
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            copyDBFromResource();
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFromResource() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String dbFilePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        try{
            inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0){
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error("Problem copying data to storage");
        }
    }
    private boolean DBExist(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=null;

        try {
            String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databasePath, null);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            Log.e("VC","SQLite Database not found");
        }

        if (db != null){
            db.close();
        }

        return db !=null ?true :false;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if (dbSQLite != null){
            dbSQLite.close();
        }
        super.close();

    }
}
```

Using Android Device Monitor I could see the database got created under `/data/data/<packagename>/databases`

When I try to perform the query to retrieve the data using this code

```
    public Cursor getSinglePasuram(int id){

        Cursor mCursor;
        String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Log.d("VC","db is "+db.getPath()+db.getVersion());
        mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from pasurams where _id = 1", null);

        return mCursor;

    }
```

Getting runtime error as table pasurams is not found.  Same query runs fine in SQLite database independently.

What is the issue with this code?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Retrieved the database file from the device to check, there is no table.  Means copy is not happening properly.

Answer (score 0):

The db used by the app differs from the one you query in SQLiteManager.
You probably added the table after a first run.

When it runs now, it already finds the *old* db and doesn't copy the *new* one from the `assets` folder.
This line `if (!dbExist){` (correctly) prevents copying the *new* db over the *old* one.

You have to delete the database from your `databases` path and re-run the app.

**[EDIT]**

This is how I copy the db

```
// Open your local db as the input stream
final InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(DB_PATH));

// Transfer the bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
final byte[] bfr = new byte[8192];//[1024];

int len = 0;

while ((len = is.read(bfr)) > 0)
{
    os.write(bfr, 0, len);
}

// Close the streams
os.flush();
os.close();
is.close();
```

Note: ctx is the Context I pass.

Comment: Tried to copy the database directly to the device and it works fine.  If I delete the database, it copied blank database.  Suspecting issue in copyDBFromResource()